# How to convert raw file to analyze format?

Tags: format, image-segmentation

I'm now in trouble with raw data.
I've a raw file(100M) with metadata.
But the tools that I'm going to use for segmentation supports only analyze format so I think I have to convert it.
Is there any way that I can realize it? I've been googling some time but most of the information I found was convert analze format to raw file.The only resource that I find might be useful is the analyzedirect.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what the format of the raw file is then you could use a Hex editor to view it, maybe excel to convert it to numbers, or use a program like Python or visual studios to create a program to convert it.

Though it would be better to give the proper name and file extensions of the file you wish to convert and the same for the resulting file that you can actually use. Also the name of the program(s) you are trying to use may help get an answer from someone too.